# Windows 10 Explorer Sometimes not displaying Length of Video

Tags: windows, windows-10, video, windows-explorer

I use windows 10 and the default file explorer. One day, some of the files started not displaying their length count anymore:

Before:
[image]
After:
[image]

I've ran into this issue before, as I was downloading videos using python's request module. The length of the videos was not displayed until the download was finished.

Does anybody know why this happens, or perhaps even how to fix this issue?

Thanks in regards :)

Comment: Windows Explorer for example doesn't know about how to decode RM Video files most likely because you don't have a codec for that format installed. VLC does not make use of the Windows codecs, instead it only uses it's internal codecs.

Comment: Thanks Robert!
I just realised it only happens on rm video files.